# `clang-format` messes up jinja templates - can I make it ignore things like `{{ ... }}` and `{% .. %}`?

Tags: c++, jinja2, clang-format

I'm working on a huge project that contains quite a few jinja templates for C++ files. I want to use `clang-format` on these templates too, but it breaks them. For example, the code

```
{{NAMESPACE | join("::")}}::{{CLASSNAME}}     {{NAMESPACE | join("::")}}::{{CLASSNAME}}::_particlesThatCanNotBeLiftedWithinTheirTree;
{{NAMESPACE | join("::")}}::{{CLASSNAME}}     {{NAMESPACE | join("::")}}::{{CLASSNAME}}::_particlesThatHaveToBeSieved;

int {{NAMESPACE | join("::")}}::{{CLASSNAME}}::_numberOfLifts                        = 0;
int {{NAMESPACE | join("::")}}::{{CLASSNAME}}::_numberOfDrops                        = 0;
int {{NAMESPACE | join("::")}}::{{CLASSNAME}}::_numberOfSieves                       = 0;
int {{NAMESPACE | join("::")}}::{{CLASSNAME}}::_numberOfReassignments                = 0;
int {{NAMESPACE | join("::")}}::{{CLASSNAME}}::_numberOfAssignmentsToGlobalSieve     = 0;
```

gets formatted into

```
{
  { NAMESPACE | join("::") }
}
::{{CLASSNAME}} {
  { NAMESPACE | join("::") }
}
::{
  { CLASSNAME }
}
::_particlesThatCanNotBeLiftedWithinTheirTree;
{
  { NAMESPACE | join("::") }
}
::{{CLASSNAME}} {
  { NAMESPACE | join("::") }
}
::{
  { CLASSNAME }
}
::_particlesThatHaveToBeSieved;


int {
  { NAMESPACE | join("::") }
}
::{
  { CLASSNAME }
}
::_numberOfLifts = 0;
int {
  { NAMESPACE | join("::") }
}
::{
  { CLASSNAME }
}
::_numberOfDrops = 0;
int {
  { NAMESPACE | join("::") }
}
::{
  { CLASSNAME }
}
::_numberOfSieves = 0;
int {
  { NAMESPACE | join("::") }
}
::{
  { CLASSNAME }
}
::_numberOfReassignments = 0;
int {
  { NAMESPACE | join("::") }
}
::{
  { CLASSNAME }
}
::_numberOfAssignmentsToGlobalSieve = 0;
```

which breaks the jinja templates.

How can I make `clang-format` work with templates like these and other jinja syntax  like `{{ ... }}` and `{% .. %}` ?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. As far as I know jinja does not use such identifiers: `NAMESPACE` and `CLASSNAME`. It's important to know what they are, clang-format is a context dependent formating tool.

Comment: what do you mean? running clang-format on the example above exactly reproduces the result I posted as well. You can literally copy-paste my initial "code" into some file, run clang-format on it without any adjustments or additional flags or configs, and obtain the result I posted.

Comment: Configuring clang-format requires detailed information about `NAMESPACE` and `CLASSNAME`, the settings are different for macros, functions, variables, constants, namespaces, types...

Comment: The file I am formatting literally contains `NAMESPACE` and `CLASSNAME`, because the file is a template for jinja to generate proper cpp files with. They are not cpp macros.

Comment: @mivkov Jinja templates are not written in C++ syntax so what `Language` parameter are you using?

Comment: `Language: Cpp`

Comment: The jinja templates follow other rules than C++. If you use `Language: Cpp`, you tell `clang-format` that the file is written in C++, and it'll try its best - but since it's not C++, it will most probably make a mess out of it.

Comment: It in fact does make a mess, hence me asking the question. However, the relevant part of the mess is that I need it to not break syntax like `{{`, `}}`, `{%`, `%}`, and `{#`, `#}`. Since it's a list of set exceptions, I thought surely there must be a way to specify that for clang-format.

Comment: I wouldn't bet on it since you tell it to interpret something written in one language, in a different language. The mess may even be in form of subtle changes that doesn't cause compilation errors (but instead causes problems in runtime). I would not use `clang-format` for a language it doesn't claim to support.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have `clang-format` do something useful with your files, you need to use the proper `Language` parameter. If your files are written in an unsupported language (or in a language not close enough to one of the supported languages), do not use `clang-format` to format the files.

The supported `Language` parameters are:

- `Cpp` - Should be used for C, C++.
- `CSharp` - Should be used for C#.
- `Java` - Should be used for Java.
- `JavaScript` - Should be used for JavaScript.
- `Json` - Should be used for JSON.
- `ObjC` - Should be used for Objective-C, Objective-C++.
- `Proto` - Should be used for Protocol Buffers (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/).
- `TableGen` - Should be used for TableGen code.
- `TextProto` - Should be used for Protocol Buffer messages in text format (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/).
- `Verilog` - Should be used for Verilog and SystemVerilog. https://standards.ieee.org/ieee/1800/6700/ https://sci-hub.st/10.1109/IEEESTD.2018.8299595